# VB.Net when the autoplay BG Music

Tags: vb.net, audio

I want to make the Background Music autoplay when the forms load. can someone help me? My code is:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.christs, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
```

Comment: Please describe your problem. What's not working?

Comment: It is working, i just want to know how to make the background music play automatically when the form loads.

Comment: Try the form load event (Form1_Load). You need to be able to stop it too when the form closes.

Comment: @AdorableVB i have another question, that 
    My.resource.christ
is my background music and I have a sound in a button which is 
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.applause, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)

But when i click the button the background music never played again,
I try the code:

    Dim sound1 As String

Dim sound2 As String

sound1 = "mySound1.wav"

sound2 = "mySound2.wav"

Me.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = sound1

Me.AxWindowsMediaPlayer2.URL = sound2


but it needs a FILEPATH and i think when i transfer to another PC it wont work.

Comment: add a fixed `URL` for your music files, so whenever you transfer it to another pc, it will work. for example, `C:\Program Files\YourFolder` or simply add it to `My.Resources`

Comment: @AdorableVB Yes sir I already did that, but my question is, if I transfer my Project to another PC, will the audio will still play??

Comment: if you get what I am saying, yes it will. But we can expect errors and bugs right? see results for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for the **on Load** event

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.christs, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
End Sub
```

And audio stops if form is **closed**

```
  Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
My.Computer.Audio.Stop(My.Resources.christs, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
End Sub
```